# Css размер текста

Tags: html5

как сделать адаптивный текст в

Answer (score 0):

Адаптивный текст задается в em,rem,%
Для этого надо сначала прописать для body{font-size: 20px;}
Остальные элементы прописываются относительно него в %, rem,em

Answer (score 0):

Открывайте страницу на весь экран и уменьшайте/увеличивайте

```css
h1 {
font-size: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
```